# My webpage only displays the PHP part and ignores all HTML

Tags: php, html

Good afternoon!

When I upload my website to my hosting partner, only the bits between my php tags are displayed on my website. I tried echoing all the html code inside the php tags, but that doesn't seem to work either. I put an echo 'test' in the code to display my problem. My file is called index.php.

The website : www.mjacartrading.nl

The top part of the code:

```
echo 'testtest';
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
    $url = "https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
include 'partials/header.php';
aCars();
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>



    <title>M.J.A. | Home</title>

</head>

   <body>
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid vh100 d-flex justify-content-center indexbgimg mb-0">
    <div class="d-flex align-self-center mobile">
        <img src="img/LOGOWHITE.png" class="indexlogo">
        <ul class="list-group antresiet mt-5 border-left border-white responsivemenu">
            <li class="list-group-item indexmenu menuactive"><a class="indexmenua" href="index.php"><b>HOME</b></a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item indexmenu"><a class="indexmenua" href="aanbod.php">AANBOD</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item indexmenu"><a class="indexmenua" href="impressie.php">IMPRESSIE</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item indexmenu"><a class="indexmenua" href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my localhost this construction works just fine. How do I display this page as intended?

Comment: Is that file really missing `<?php` at the very top?

Answer (score -1):

We'd need a more complete version of the code to know for sure. Some ideas though:

1. In the code you've posted you are missing the opening `<?php`. That should be on the line before your opening `echo 'testtest';`
2. Check you are using `<?php`, not `<?`, as the open php tag
3. Check you have any included files on the server
   your code is looking for `partials/header.php`, make sure that's been uploaded too.
4. Finally it's possible that your server does not have php installed / setup correctly.

Hope that helps.